# I used "FIND MY DEVICE" feature. Now phone wont start

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, boot-loop, unbricking, xiaomi-mi4

I went to *Google Dashboard - Find My Device* and tried the **PLAY SOUND**.

The phone got into non-responsive state.
I tried to reboot the phone, but now my phone doesn't boot.

Device is ***XIAOMI REDMI NOTE 4***

Please let me know what should I do!

Comment: What do you mean by non responsive? Is it not restarting or powering off?

Comment: @Weezy it is not going beyond splash screen. Does the phone get bricked by this feature of android ?